# Count traffic separately for each SIM on 2SIM MTK-based phone

Tags: java, android

Any app I could find on GPlay counts traffic for both SIM while in Settings-Data Usage traffic is counted for each SIM. I used jd-gui to see how it's done and have found that classes from private API were used.

```
import android.net.INetworkStatsService;
import android.net.INetworkStatsService.Stub;
import android.net.INetworkStatsSession;
import android.net.NetworkPolicy;
import android.net.NetworkPolicyManager;
import android.net.NetworkStats;
import android.net.NetworkStats.Entry;
import android.net.NetworkStatsHistory;
import android.net.NetworkStatsHistory.Entry;
import android.net.NetworkTemplate;
```

Can I use reflection to use them?

Update.
I've tried to use Reflection. Executing this code give me an exception "java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class android.net.INetworkStatsService"

```
        Class<Object> MyINetworkStatsService = null;
    try {
        MyINetworkStatsService = (Class<Object>) Class.forName("android.net.INetworkStatsService");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Object mStatsService = null;
    try {
        mStatsService = MyINetworkStatsService != null ? MyINetworkStatsService.newInstance() : null;
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Upd. Because both StatsService and StatsSession are interfaces, I can't instantiate them and should use Proxy. Can anyone help with that?

Upd. I've made an effort

```
        String id = getActiveSubscriberId(mContext);
    try {
        Object tmpl = null;
        long stats = 0;
        Class<?> a = Class.forName("android.net.NetworkTemplate");
        Class<?> b = Class.forName("android.net.INetworkStatsService");
        Method getState = b.getMethod("getNetworkTotalBytes", a, long.class, long.class);
        Method[] am = a.getDeclaredMethods();
        Method getTemplate = null;
        for (Method m : am) {
            if (m.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("buildTemplateMobileAll")) {
                getTemplate = m;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (getTemplate != null) {
            getTemplate.setAccessible(true);
            tmpl = getTemplate.invoke(a.getClass(), id);
        }
        Object object = Proxy.newProxyInstance(b.getClass().getClassLoader(), b.getInterfaces(), new InvocationHandler() {
            public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                if (method.getName().equals("getNetworkTotalBytes")) {
                    return method.invoke(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);
                }
                throw new RuntimeException("no method found");
            }
        });            
        Object[] args = {b.getClass(), tmpl, Long.MIN_VALUE, Long.MAX_VALUE};
        stats = (long) ((b.getClass()) object).getState(args);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e0) {
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e0) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e0) {
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e0) {
    }
```

But it says that there is an error "Method call expected" in

```
stats = (long) ((b.getClass()) object).getState(args);
```

If I change this string like this

```
stats = (long) ((b) object).getState(args);
```

I get another error - "Unknown class: 'b'"

Comment: Were u able to get the instance of INetworkStatsService??